# Android Callable Wrappers

Tags: android, dll, xamarin.android

I have created a mono android library. And now I need to port that library from c# to java project. So I made that library with android callable wrappers and i got wrappers for my dll. I included those wrappers, but I can't able to reference the dll in my android java project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a Mono for Android DLL from a Java project. A standard Java Android application isn't going to include the Mono runtime, which is required to understand and execute any code compiled into a Mono for Android library.